# Powershell replacing quotation marks with vertical lines

Tags: powershell

I am currently near the end of an online workshop for my Networking and Cyber Security Class. The workshop is telling me to end the commands

```
New-Website -Name nlbport -PhysicalPath "c:\nlbport" -port 6789
```

However whenever I try to do this, powershell keeps replacing my quotation marks with vertical lines `|` . Obviously, because there isn't supposed to be vertical lines, my commands won't run and I can't check off this online workshops. I'm clueless as to why this is happening and any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say that PowerShell is replacing the quotation marks; do you mean that when you run the script you're seeing pipe characters (`|`) appearing somewhere?  If so, where / can you share that output with us?  Or do you mean that the incorrect character is used as you're typing the command in / before you run anything?

Comment: Probably your keyboard definition/language is not what you expect. Press **Shift + Alt** to switch between languages until you have the correct one or read [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-languages-using-the-language-bar-1c2242c0-fe15-4bc3-99bc-535de6f4f258). As an alternative, you can get the `"` character bij typing **Alt + 34** (on the numeric keyboard)